# Kafka: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null & Node -1 disconnected

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-kafka-connect

I used Kafka 2.5.1 before and the program ran well. Rencently, the version of Kafka has been changed to 3.4.0, and the Kafka server online is 2.8.1. Then, when I start the program, some exception info appears.
At the beginning, it shows that.

```java
2023-08-02 16:14:24.892  INFO 48784 --- [est,test1,test2] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sos2-1, groupId=sos2] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 101578:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null

Then, about nine minutes passed, it shows that.
2023-08-02 16:23:01.824  INFO 48784 --- [ad | producer-3] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-3] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-08-02 16:23:06.216  INFO 48784 --- [est,test1,test2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-sos2-1, groupId=sos2] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-08-02 16:23:10.299  INFO 48784 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-08-02 16:23:10.844  INFO 48784 --- [ad | producer-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Node -1 disconnected.
```

However, when I see the Kafka Server, the connection still works. The message can be received and sended by my program correctly. It just show some exception info but didnt affect the function of my program. I am afraid that some problems may happen in the future. Why does these info appear at the beginning.

When I change the Kafka version to 2.5.1, these info disapper, but the version must be 3.4.0 due to some reasons. I guess these info appear due to the version difference. I hope someone can give some help!